# File permissions question

Tags: java, php, file, permissions

If I need a php-page to have access to upload images and move images from a folder on the server, what permissions would I set on the folder then?

I know we have "Owner", "Group", and "Others".
But what does the server (or the php-code itself) count as? Owner?

Also, would I need to set the php-page with the upload script with some specific permissions to be able to upload the files? Is it execute permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on which user the server is run as. The web server is often run as "Other", but that's not always the case so I suggest you ask your sysadmin or hosting provider.
2. No, you don't need to set any special permissions on the upload script, only on the folder you're uploading to.